# Bash - reading wildcard patterns from a file into an array

Tags: arrays, bash, wildcard

I want to read a list of patterns that may (probably do) contain wildcards from a file

The patterns might look like this:

```
/vobs/of_app/unix/*
/vobs/of_app/bin/*
```

etc

My first attempt was to do this:

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(cat $file))
```

This worked fine when the patterns did not match anything in the filesystem, but when they did match things in the filesystem, they got expanded so instead of containing the patterns, my array contained the directory listings of the specified directories.  This was no good.

I next tried quoting like this

```
array=("$(cat $file)")
```

But this dumped the entire contents of the file into the 0th element of the array.

How can I prevent it from expanding the wildcards into directory listings while still putting each line of the file into a separate array element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array=()
while read line; do
    array+=("$line")
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Ok, I found the elsewhere on the web and it looks pretty good, but I'm having one problem with it.  Later in my code, I'm iterating through the list of patterns and comparing a string to each of them to see if they match, using if [[ "$string" = "$pattern" ]] - this was working fine before but now it is not identifying matches, and when I use set -xv to see what's going on, it appears that there are backslashes (escapes?) inserted into my data.  For example: + [[ /vobscm/ld_app/unix/adp/install/6UPSTINS.SSM = \*\/\u\n\i\x\/\* ]] (where the pattern on the right was originally read as */unix/*

Comment: The `i` variable is unnecessary. Just use `array+=("$line")` to append to the array.

Comment: This site is doing weird things to my asterisks but that very end of my previous comment should have read as \*/unix/\*

Comment: Asterisk is used to indicate italic text in comments. If you want it literal, put it in backticks to signify code, e.g. `*/unix/*`.

Comment: Don't put the pattern in quotes inside `[[ ]]`. Use `if [[ $string = $pattern ]]`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it.  I need $string in quotes because it might contain spaces, but $pattern does not need to be able to.

Answer (score 5):

Bash 4 introduced `readarray`:

```
readarray -t array < "$file"
```

and you're done.

Comment: sadly, I seem to be running basion 3.2.25

Comment: I like `mapfile` better than `readarray` (but it's just a matter of personal taste). `+1` anyways, this is Bash (>=4) way of doing.